# Roles in Sonata Admin

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

Good day. I can not understand how in sonata admin bundle to add roles to users. Namely, it is necessary that the user with a specific role seen in adminpanel only one entity and only worked with her. For now, there is only one role - it ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN, which gives access to the whole adminpanel. On [official site](http://www.sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/reference/security.html) found just such an example :

```
security:
    ...
    role_hierarchy:
        # for convenience, I decided to gather Sonata roles here
        ROLE_SONATA_FOO_READER:
            - ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN_DEMO_FOO_LIST
            - ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN_DEMO_FOO_VIEW
        ROLE_SONATA_FOO_EDITOR:
            - ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN_DEMO_FOO_CREATE
            - ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN_DEMO_FOO_EDIT
        ROLE_SONATA_FOO_ADMIN:
            - ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN_DEMO_FOO_DELETE
            - ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN_DEMO_FOO_EXPORT
        # those are the roles I will use (less verbose)
        ROLE_STAFF:             [ROLE_USER, ROLE_SONATA_FOO_READER]
        ROLE_ADMIN:             [ROLE_STAFF, ROLE_SONATA_FOO_EDITOR, ROLE_SONATA_FOO_ADMIN]
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN:       [ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]
```

But I can not understand that instead embed DEMO, and that instead of FOO. Tried a lot of options but nothing is worked.

Thanks in advance and sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 0):

The permissions are:

- LIST: view the list of objects
- VIEW: view the detail of one object
- CREATE: create a new object
- EDIT: update an existing object
- DELETE: delete an existing object
- EXPORT (for the native Sonata export links)

Comment: That's understandable. Other unclear. That instead of FOO and DEMO.

Comment: That depends on your service declaration. For example, if you have declared your service like this `sonata.admin.demo.foo` Sonata will check if the user has the ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN_DEMO_FOO_EDIT/LIST/VIEW...