# How correctly manage role and give just read permission to a user in sonata with FOSbundle?

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle, sonata-admin

I am doing a Sonata project, I manage my database with Doctrine and my user login with FOSbundle. I am trying to give different right to my user. I have an entity named Suivi, this is a screen shot of my current Suivi list menu. As you can see on the right side there are different button(display, edit, delete):

[image: screenshot]

I would like to hide edit and delete button to certain user and like this just give to them read permission.

So I create a ROLE_SONATA_SUIVI_READER in my security.yml inspired by this link:

[Roles in Sonata Admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22380625/roles-in-sonata-admin)

/app/config/security.yml

```
security:
encoders:
    FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: bcrypt

role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_SONATA_SUIVI_READER:
        - ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN_DEMO_SUIVI_LIST
        - ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN_DEMO_SUIVI_VIEW
    ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN
    ROLE_DEFAULT:     ROLE_SONATA_SUIVI_READER

providers:
    fos_userbundle:
        id: fos_user.user_provider.username_email

firewalls:

    console:
        pattern: ^/_console
        anonymous: false
        security: true
        logout:       true
        http_basic: ~
    main:
        pattern: ^/
        form_login:
            provider: fos_userbundle
            csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager
            default_target_path: /admin/dashboard
        logout:
          path:       fos_user_security_logout
          target:     fos_user_security_login
        anonymous:    true


access_control:
    - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_DEFAULT }
```

/src/AppBundle/Admin/SuiviAdmin.yml

```
  protected function configureListFields(ListMapper $listMapper)
{
    $listMapper
      ->add('phylica', null, array('associated_property' => 'numeroPlant'))
      ->add('phenologie','text',array('label'=>'Phénologie'))
      ->add('traitement','text',array('label'=>'Traitement'))
      ->add('competition','text',array('label'=>'Compétition'))
      ->add('predation','text',array('label'=>'Prédation'))
      ->add('periode','text',array('label'=>'Période'))
      ->add('saison')
      ->add('hauteurMaximumCm','text',array('label'=>'Hauteur Max(cm)'))
      ->add('dbhB','text',array('label'=>'dbh b'))
      ->add('dbhH','text',array('label'=>'dbh h'))
      ->add('mort','text',array('label'=>'Mort'))
      ->add('nonTrouve','text',array('label'=>'Non trouvé'))
      ->add('_action', null, array(
        'actions' => array(
          'show' => array(),
          'edit' => array(),
          'delete' => array(),
        )
      ));
}
```

This is my fos_user settings in config:

/app/config/config.yml

```
fos_user:
db_driver: orm
firewall_name: main
user_class: AppBundle\Entity\User

registration:
    form:
        type: AppBundle\Form\RegistrationFormType
group:
    group_class: AppBundle\Entity\Group

service:
    mailer: fos_user.mailer.default
from_email:
    address: "%mailer_user%"
    sender_name: "%mailer_user%"
resetting:
     email:
        from_email:
            address:        toto@gmail.com
            sender_name:    Demo Resetting
```

According to symfony's documentation(https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/security.html), I think that I can do something like this in a twig file:

```
{% if is_granted('ROLE_ADMIN') %}
    <p>DISPLAY SOMETHING</p>
{% endif %}
```

But this solution doesn't not satisfy me, this is not the FOSbundle way to do things and I don't want to overright a Sonata twig file.
If anyone has a solution... Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am not sure I understand your issue - could you clarify what you mean by "FOSbundle way", specifically what you dislike about the solution your provide and which way you are hoping to achieve it instead?

Comment: OK. First I forgot to precise than I use SonataAdminBundle but not SonataUserBundle. When I say "FOSbundle way", I mean a way to hide my edit and delete button without add a Twig file in my project. I find my project more clear when I have less Twig file added. I suppose than Sonata allows you to do this, without overwritten his default twig file, by using ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN_DEMO_FOO_VIEW. (https://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/reference/security.html).